# MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" doesnt work

Tags: .net, asp.net

I set that property on my page, but it doesn't work. What are other ways of achieving holding position on the page between the postbacks?

Comment: Are you using ajax postbacks?

Comment: Weird, I've used that a bunch and it's worked fine for me.  Can you post some of your code so we can see what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX UpdatePanel to maintain scroll position.